# how can you point the head of an arrow from text bubbles to an equation in LaTex?

Tags: latex, xelatex

I could create a page like this:

[image: screen shot of the result]

using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, calc} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\myfont}{Arial}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand\commentary[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture, baseline={(here.base)}] \node (here) {#1};%
\marginpar{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \begin{scope}[rotate=(rand*10),shift={(1.8,0)}]
        \node [text width=3cm, align=center, transform shape] (text) at (0, 0) {\footnotesize \myfont #2};
        \draw [transform shape, thick] plot [smooth, tension=0.8] coordinates {
          ($(text.south) + (-10pt, -5pt) + (rand * 2pt, rand * 2pt)$) 
          ($(text.south east) + (-5pt, 5pt)$)
          ($(text.north east) + (rand * 2pt - 5pt, rand * 2pt)$)
          ($(text.north west) + (rand * 2pt + 5pt, rand * 2pt)$)
          ($(text.south west) + (rand * 2pt + 5pt, rand * 2pt)$)
          ($(text.south) + (10pt, -3pt) + (rand * 2pt, rand * 2pt)$)
        };
    \end{scope}
    \draw[->, thick] ($(text.south west) - (-10pt, 5pt)$)  to [bend left=20] ($(here.south east) - (3pt, 2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}

\begin{document}
The equation of a plane through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ \commentary{is:}{The tangent plane: $\nabla f(\mathbf{x})\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)=0$.}
$$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$$
The vector $(a,b,c)$ is normal to the plane. 


\end{document}
```

(1) How can put the head of the arrow to the equation (for example to + sign in the display question) instead of a word in the text (intead of "is :" in this example)?

(2) How can I move the text bubble 1 cm to up or down?

Comment: You probably will have better luck with this on the [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions).